# I am getting error fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found while running brew install --HEAD usbmuxd

Tags: flutter, homebrew

I am trying to run command
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
but each time it throw this error

```
/usr/local/include/plist/Node.h:26:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#include <cstddef>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [collection.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wswitch-default -Wno-unused-parameter -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -g -O2 -c thread.c -o thread.o >/dev/null 2>&1
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [socket.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Please, help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please run `brew doctor`, fix all the warnings that mention unexpected header files, and try again.

Comment: @bfontaine  Already tried that..but it doesn't help in my case

Comment: There’s a closed issue open in usbmuxd’s github for this issue but unfortunately its author didn’t write how they fixed it before closing the issue :/
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/593

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29280) way back when a wrong header file was placed on /usr/local/include. Running `brew doctor` and removing `/usr/local/include/string.h` should solve the issue.